# How do I get the value of an attribute in a json object

Tags: javascript, json, attributes

how do I correctly get the value of an object using a string?

I have the following code:

```
let o = { dispatcher: { initials: 'abc' } }
o["dispatcher.initials"]
# undefined
```

The string I get already comes like this "dispatcher.initials". Can not I use a string like this?

I expected to get the value `abc`

Comment: `o.dispatcher.initials` or `o["dispatcher"]["initials"]`

Comment: the string I get already comes like this `"dispatcher.initials"`. Can not I use a string like this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a function to get you property from path then you can use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let o = { dispatcher: { initials: 'abc' } }

const getVal = (obj,path) => path.split('.').reduce((ac,a) => (ac || {})[a],obj);

console.log(getVal(o,"dispatcher.initials"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `split` the string and `reduce` to loop thru the array.

```js
let o = { dispatcher: { initials: 'abc' } };
let str = "dispatcher.initials";

let result = str.split(".").reduce((c,v)=> c != null ? c[v] : null ,o);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your code will throw error if the path is broken. Second problem is that if there is only this single path so why not do `o.dispatcher.initials`